# ajax call and the difference between not reached and not answered

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, networking, tcp

I'm working on a javascript application which tries to reach something in the local network. Some calls are kind of synchronous in the way that the next action could only be performed after recieving a response (or at least, an error). The host needs several seconds for some of those requests. If the host is not reachable, I want to switch to another host to do the call.

The problem is, if I specify a timeout like 40 seconds, I have to wait those 40 seconds, without a difference if the host is not reachable or just needs some time to answer.

Is it somehow possible to detect if the host has accepted and recieved the Request but not sent an answer or if the host has not been reached yet? For example to use the normal networktimeout of some seconds to reach the host and a long timeout to wait for answer?

Comment: xmlhttprequest only has `opened` for readystate, which means send() has been called. doesn't give any information at the tcp level, e.g. "waiting for dns" or "waiting for tcp handshake" type stuff.

Comment: the documentations out there about readystate sound very promising, since "2" is for "sent request"

unfortunately it is not true, you get instantly "1"
if the host is reached, and when the response is there you get 2,3 and 4
if the host is not reached, after timeout, you get 4

so it seems that there really is nothing in javascript to detect a successful connection :( but thx for your comment